# How to delete entry from sip_regisration table?

Tags: mysql, voip, freeswitch

We connect freeswitch using odbc connection for device registration on server.

Now the problem occur when Freeswitch crashed,down or restart uncertainly that time the entry does not removed from sip_registration table and next time user are not able to make the call.

Then we have to manually delete that entry from database to make it working.

> OS : Debian8
>
> FS version : FreeSWITCH Version 1.6.6~64bit ( 64bit)

can anybody help us to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The are multiple solutions:

- have Nagios/Icinga check your freeswitch (send OPTIONS to 5060). If this fails your freeswitch is down. You can then have Nagios execute a script that cleans up your database.
- have a simple (I use python) server listen on freeswitch ESL (Event Socket Layer) and act on (re-)Start events. So if your freeswitch is started, this server will do some things to cleanup your database.
- Make some changes to the freeswitch startup script so it will do this housekeeping on startup
- have a cronjob every minute or so delete all entries in sip_registration table that are older than the uptime of the freeswitch process.

But, after all, you should focus on why freeswitch crashed. That's your biggest problem, all the other is damage control...

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i can not do this because it will delete all users
while i want to remove some specific users only.

Comment: You can delete only entries with corresponding hostname

Comment: By the way, we found that odbc is causing crashes on multiple occasions, so we connect without odbc (to postgres on localhost)